# Joda-time DateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay() wrong result in date (2036,3,21) with Asia/Tehran time zone

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime

In Joda-Time version 2.9.9 I want to remove time part of `DateTime` variable.

Only for time zone `Asia/Tehran` and some dates like (2036-03-21, 2037-03-21, ...) it returns `1:00:00` in time part of result.

I also checked the Joda-Time source code but I couldn't find any problem.

The code is:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2036, 03, 21, 10, 0, DateTimeZone.forID(Asia/Tehran));
dt = dt.withTimeAtStartOfday();
```

Actual result:

> 2036-03-21T0**1:00:00.000**+04:30

Expected result:

> 2036-03-21T**00:00:00.000**+04:30

Time is not zero. This only happens for zone `Asia/Tehran`.

My system config:

- Java version: 1.7.0_72 - *I have to use Java 7*
- Joda-Time: 2.9.9

I solved this problem by converting `DateTime` to `LocalDate`, but I want to know why this problem happens?

Comment: What do you get if you look at the 21st of September?

Comment: Did you read the [Javadocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--)?

Comment: "I solved this problem by converting DateTime to LocalDate" did you? A LocalDate has no time component, so the value would have not contained the hour you expect.

Comment: This problem happens only for dates after 2036-03-21 and only for 21st of March each year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Iran switches from Standard time to Daylight Savings time at 00:00 on the 21st or 22nd of March (whichever day contains the astronomical equinox).
In 2036 this happens on the 21st.  [In 2018 it happens to fall on the 22nd](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran).

In short, the time jumps from `2036/03/20 24:00` to `2036/03/21 01:00`.  The hour from midnight to 1 AM does not exist on that specific day.

When writing code that deals with time, ALWAYS keep in mind that unexpected small offsets from expected results are almost surely due to administrative time changes.  This is even more true for historical dates, where offsets could be any number of minutes and seconds, not just whole or half-hours.

Comment: i know about daylight saving time in start of spring  (21st of March)in iran.  But for year:2035 why this method(withTimeAtStartOfday()) returns '2035-03-21T00:00:00' ?

Comment: Because the time at the start of the day is 01:00